# Is it true that we cannot login to SharePoint 2016 from iOS with HTTPS?

Tags: 2016, authentication, mobile

We have a fresh new SharePoint 2016 farm with HTTPS.
We are trying to connect to this farm using different mobile devices. When we are using iPhones and Safari the website just keeps asking for credentials over and over again.

Other mobile devices seem to be fine.

I've found this on StackOverflow:

> This issue occurs as the SharePoint Authentication is not compatible with the IOS
>
> As of now this issue has been reported but the change is required from
>   the Apple end, such that the iOS accepts the SharePoint
>   Authentication.

Is there any official statement from Microsoft that admits this problem?

**Update**

My Client tried their MAC and they get a problem there as well:

[image]

Accessing the site from the laptop worked for them.

Comment: what is your IOS version?

Comment: it's iOS 10.3.2.

Comment: have you tried Chrome browser on the IOS device?

Comment: I did, I had the same problem with Chrome

Comment: people having issue, what we did is just use the desktop site on it ipads. have u tried mobile app for it

Comment: We didn't. But I've heard that it  too had a problem authenticating against SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I've just solved it.

I've disabled HTTP/2 by creating two registry keys: under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

```
EnableHttp2Tls REG_DWORD 0
EnableHttp2Cleartext REG_DWORD 0
```

[image]

After the registry change I had to restart the server. Only after that I was able to login to the site from Apple devices.